# Likelihood of coin toss sequences

Tags: probability

I have a process, which is a person flipping a coin 1000 times and recording the results.  I'm given some possible sequences, one of which came from coin flips and some which didn't (generated in some other way). I'd like to do a hypothesis test where I score the sequences (and normalize if needed) in order to find the sequence most likely to have come from the actual coin tossing along with my confidence in that decision.

Thinking about it in the most basic way, every sequence is equally probable; any sequence I pick has a 1/2^1000 chance.  On the other hand, I can look at other statistics such as the total number of heads.  It is vanishingly improbable to get a sequence of 1000 heads in a row because the expected number of heads is 500 and the standard deviation is about 15 (from binomial distribution).  So on that basis, I prefer ones that have about the right number of heads.  But I also don't want the first half to be heads and the second half tails...  hopefully you can see where I'm going.

Is there a rigorous/correct way to compute sequence likelihoods?

Comment: Generated by tosses of a fair coin, or generated by tosses of a coin, fair or not?

Comment: A key point is to decide your test before you see the actual data.

Comment: What are the sequences look like?

Comment: Yeah, a fair coin, and as the person doing the scoring, you know it's a fair coin.  Example:  I flip 10 times and generate a sequence.  I make up two more sequences.  The sequences are:

HHTHTTHTTH  and HHHHHHHHHH and HHHHHTTTTT

The first one is more likely to have come from the (fair) coin toss.  What method of scoring will give that result?